# Moving image file to the folder inside the S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x

"Hi all below is my code iam trying to move the file from local repository to the folder which sits
inside the s3 bucket but from below code name of the local file alone moving to folder which sits
inside the s3 bucket instead i want to move entire .png and jpeg images can any one help"

-

Comment: def s3_image(request):
    path="C:/Users/17995/Desktop/proj_manag_git/pmt-api/media/screenShots/758"
    data=os.listdir(path)
    print('g',data)
    for i in data:
        bucket_name = s3_Bucket_name
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-south-1', aws_access_key_id = S3_access_key, aws_secret_access_key=S3_secret_key)
        result=s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=('758'+'/'+i))
        print(result)

Comment: sorry about the allignment above s my code